# Remove default WordPress widgets

Tags: widgets

Hey guys here is the problem I have added 2 sidebars to my blog, however when I change their visibility to only appear on front page and when I click on a specific post ALL of the default widgets available appear for some reason. How do I change that?

Comment: How are you setting widget's visibility, are you using any plugin ?

Comment: I am setting the invisibility correct the problem is where I set them to hidden ALL the default plug-ins appear. The problem is in the template it overrides with the plug-in I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpsites_remove_default_widgets() {
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Pages');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Calendar');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Archives');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Links');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Meta');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Search');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Categories');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Comments');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_RSS');
     unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud');
     unregister_widget('WP_Nav_Menu_Widget');
 }
 add_action('widgets_init', 'wpsites_remove_default_widgets', 11);
```

Add this in your functions file or a site specific plugin.

Uses [`unregister widget`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget)